# Call function in another ViewController depending on parameter passed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to setup a handler function for Alamofire, which I'll use in my iPhone app (Swift 3). I've got the helper function setup great as shown below, but I want it to call different success functions depending on where I'm using it in my project.

Helper class in Helper.swift file:

```
class Helper {

    static func toServer(urlString: String,
                         postParams: [String:Any],
                          buttons: [UIButton],
                          messageLabel: UILabel,
                          spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView,
                          successMethod: Method) {

        // Working State
        // Hide buttons passed to this function so user can't tap them
        for button in buttons {
            button.isHidden = true
        }
        // Show the activity indicator
        spinner.isHidden = false
        // Hide the message
        messageLabel.isHidden = true

        let parameters: Parameters = postParams
        // Send the http call
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure:
                //print(error)
                // Hide the activity indicator
                spinner.isHidden = true
                // Show error message
                messageLabel.text = "No Internet. Try again".uppercased()
                messageLabel.isHidden = false
                // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap them again
                for button in buttons {
                    button.isHidden = false
                }
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                let code = json["code"] as? Int,
                let response = json["response"] as? String {
                    if code != 1 {
                        // Server (json data) didn't return success
                        // Hide the activity indicator
                        spinner.isHidden = true
                        // Show unsuccessful data entry by the user
                        messageLabel.text = response.uppercased()
                        messageLabel.isHidden = false
                        // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap on them
                        for button in buttons {
                            button.isHidden = false
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Server (json data) returned success (a 1)
                        // Call the success function passed to this function as a parameter and send it the json data sent by the server
                        successMethod(json: json)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Print the response for debugging
                    print(response)
                    // Hide the activity indicator
                    spinner.isHidden = true
                    // Show error message to the user
                    messageLabel.text = "App error \(#line)".uppercased()
                    messageLabel.isHidden = false
                    // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap them
                    for button in buttons {
                        button.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then I would call it various times in various ViewController classes in various other .swift files within the project, such as this but with different parameters each time according to the ViewController and situation I'm in:

```
    Helper.toServer("https://example.com/page.php", 
postParams: ["email":email.text!.trimmingCharacters(in:NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)], 
buttons: [registerButton], 
messageLabel: message, 
spinner: spinner, 
successMethod: self.successFunction(json: [String:Any]))
```

It's giving me an error message on successMethod(json:json) saying "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer'). I know I'm not doing it right. Please give me guidance. I'm simply trying to use a helper function so I don't have to call all the URL request handling items every time I want to make a URL request, but I can't figure out how to have the success function be variable. Do I need to use #selector as a parameter?

Comment: Passing in a block would seem like the Swift-y thing to do.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Care to elaborate with a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Interneting and testing (and with the direction of Phillip Mills), I found a solution. I'm posting in case anyone finds it helpful:

In a .swift file:

class Helper {

```
class func toServer(_ urlString: String,
                         postParams: [String:Any],
                         buttons: [UIButton],
                         messageLabel: UILabel,
                         spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView,
                         success:@escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void) {

    // Working State
    // Hide buttons passed to this function so user can't tap them
    for button in buttons {
        button.isHidden = true
    }
    // Show the activity indicator
    spinner.isHidden = false
    // Hide the message
    messageLabel.isHidden = true

    let parameters: Parameters = postParams
    // Send the http call
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure:
            //print(error)
            // Hide the activity indicator
            spinner.isHidden = true
            // Show error message
            messageLabel.text = "No Internet. Try again".uppercased()
            messageLabel.isHidden = false
            // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap them again
            for button in buttons {
                button.isHidden = false
            }
        case .success:
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                let code = json["code"] as? Int,
                let message = json["response"] as? String {
                if code != 1 {
                    // Server (json data) didn't return success
                    // Hide the activity indicator
                    spinner.isHidden = true
                    // Show unsuccessful data entry by the user
                    messageLabel.text = message.uppercased()
                    messageLabel.isHidden = false
                    // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap on them
                    for button in buttons {
                        button.isHidden = false
                    }
                } else {
                    // Server (json data) returned success (a 1)
                    let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
                    success(json!)
                }
            } else {
                // Print the response for debugging
                print(response)
                // Hide the activity indicator
                spinner.isHidden = true
                // Show error message to the user
                messageLabel.text = "App error \(#line)".uppercased()
                messageLabel.isHidden = false
                // Show buttons passed to this function so user can tap them
                for button in buttons {
                    button.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And when I want to use them in any other file/ViewController:

```
Helper.toServer("https://example.com/page", postParams: ["email":email.text!, "password":password.text!], buttons: [registerButton, anotherButton], messageLabel: message, spinner: spinner, success: {
                (JSONResponse) -> Void in
                print(JSONResponse)

                // Do stuff with JSON result now that it's a success
            })
```